# redirection in html failed

Tags: python, html, css, django

I have a html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<div style="margin:0 auto; width:900px">
<ul id="nav">
<li id="notification_li">
<a href="#" id="notificationLink">
<div id="notify"> <img src="{% static "images/notification.png" %}" width="20" height="20" />
{% if unseen_notifications.count > 0 %}
    <span id="notification_count">
    {{unseen_notifications.count}}</span>
{% endif %}
</div></a>
<div id="notificationContainer">
<div id="notificationTitle">Inbox</div>
<div id="notificationsBody">
<a href="/home/">Home</a>
</div>
<div id="notificationFooter"><a href="{% url "ask_question" %}">See All</a></div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Here I have "Home" inside id "notificationContainer". When I click Home it doesnt redirect but outside "notificationContainer" it redirects. Inside notification container I am willing to put notifications. But it doesnt redirect.

My style for this:

```
#notification_li{position:relative}
#notificationContainer {
background-color: #FFF;
border: 1px solid rgba(100, 100, 100, .4);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
overflow: visible;
position: absolute;
top: 30px;
margin-left: -170px;
width: 400px;
z-index: 11;
display: none;
}
#notificationContainer:before {
content: '';
display: block;
position: absolute;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border: 10px;
margin-top: -20px;
margin-left: 188px;
}
#notificationTitle {
z-index: 1000;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 8px;
font-size: 15px;
background-color: #ffffff;
width: 384px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
#notificationsBody {
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
margin: 0px;
min-height:300px;
font-size:14px; 
display: block;
}
#notificationsBody a{ color: #000;}
#notification_count {
padding: 3px 7px 3px 7px;
background: #cc0000;
color: #ffffff;
font-weight: bold;
margin-left: 0px;
border-radius: 20px;
position: absolute;
margin-top: -7px;
font-size: 11px;
}
#notificationFooter {
background-color: #e9eaed;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 8px;
font-size: 12px;
border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a URL in your urls.py
and if you want to use it like this `<a href="{% url "ask_question" %}">` then add a name to your url and use it like this  `<a href="{% url "home" %}">`

if your home has a view then:

```
url(r'^people/', "myapp.views.people", name="people"),
```

if it is only a template you can use something like this:

```
url(r'^home/',TemplateView.as_view(template_name="homepage.html"), name="home"),
```

Comment: I have url in my urls.py

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood Ebtessam's answer. Not only do you need to configure the URL, you also need to reference that URL correctly in the HTML.

## You have:

```
<a href="/home/">Home</a>
```

## Change to:

```
<a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a>
```

The above assumes that within your URL you defined something that looks similar to:

```
url(r'^home/',views.your_home_view_here, name="home"),
```

Notice the `name="home"`.In your template you reference the view with that name, hence:

`{% url 'home' %}`

Comment: if u see at the bottom I have configured url in See All like u said.. Its not working too.. N yeah I have configured it in way u said. If I put same url outside notification container its working but not inside notificationcontainer. I think there is problem in style...

Comment: Can you post your urls.py?

Comment: Its error in the css. I have used this facebook style notification from a site and I checked it. Even there it dont redirect anything inside the notification container. I am not a front end developer so I dont know whats wrong but even there I saw the same issue. Click inside notification container is disabled...

Comment: Well the only error I see in your CSS is that you're missing a semi-colon after 'relative' in #notification_li{position:relative}. Besides that the only other piece that MIGHT be causing a problem is the #notificationContainer:before{...} chunk of code but if that's not the problem then I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: http://www.codelessons.info/2014/11/facebook-style-notification-popup-using.html............ check it out here....

Comment: Well the page you linked says that it does not exist and has only one 'Home' link that I can find and it works fine for me.

Comment: http://demos.codelessons.info/facebook_style_notification/     home works not notification